# Breezejs Query with Filter containing enum

Tags: filter, enums, breeze

Prior to one of the latest releases I could use a predicate like following:

`(myEntity.myEnum, '<', 100) -`

this no longer works as enums are treated like strings

how do we filter on an enum then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the 'name' of the enumerated value. For example

On the server:

```
public enum RoleType {
  Guest = 0,
  Restricted = 1,
  Standard = 2,
  Admin = 3
```

}

To query:

```
var query = new EntityQuery("Roles").where("roleType", "==", 'Restricted');
```

Comment: Yep - issue was the nuget package didn't update the server-side code...meh... thanks!